# ListView with FTP VB.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I want to display the directories and files on my FTP server on a ListView. I am new to ListViews so could someone please help me start?

Code:

```
Dim newSelected As TreeNode = e.Node
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        Dim nodeDirInfo As DirectoryInfo = _
        CType(newSelected.Tag, DirectoryInfo)
        Dim subItems() As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
        Dim item As ListViewItem = Nothing

        Dim dir As DirectoryInfo
        For Each dir In nodeDirInfo.GetDirectories()
            item = New ListViewItem(dir.Name, 0)
            subItems = New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() _
                {New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "Directory"), _
                New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, _
                dir.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())}

            item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems)
            ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        Next dir
        Dim file As FileInfo
        For Each file In nodeDirInfo.GetFiles()
            item = New ListViewItem(file.Name, 1)
            subItems = New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() _
                {New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"), _
                New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, _
                file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())}

            item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems)
            ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        Next file
```

Comment: I tried connecting to it..  and it worked but I get all the files and no directories ? I'll post my code now..

Comment: `TreeView` or `ListView`?

Comment: Sorry ListView my bad :P

Comment: Is this a question about listviews or ftp? They are two very different questions with two very different answers

Answer (score 0):

If no directories are being added to the Listview, It is likely because `nodeDirInfo.GetDirectories` is empty. Set a breakpoint and check its contents. It may have nothing to do with the ListView itself. Are there any subdirectories in the path NewSelected.Tag?